# Is my approach to this limit true?

Tags: calculus, limits, elementary-number-theory, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{t-n}{t}\bigg)$$

Using the limit definition of $e$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\bigg(1+\frac{1}{n}\bigg)^n=e$$

the required limit can be written as

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{n}{t}\bigg)$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty}\bigg(1-\frac{n}{t}\bigg)^{t/t}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-n/t}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Is my approach true?

I have solved this limit using the limit definition of e. But the answer I am getting is completely different from the original answer i.e 1. Please help me in identifying the correct answer.

Comment: I think the problem is in the last step: when you take the limit as $t$ approaches infinity first, what will you get in the exponent for any finite $n$?

Comment: Since $\lim_{t\to \infty }\frac{t-n}{t}=1$, your limit should be 1

Comment: Stephen Donovan, I  have assumed that as 't' approach infinity the value of 1/t goes towards dx(infinitesimal). So e^(-ndx) as n approach infinity it approaches e^(-1)=1/e. Am I right?

Comment: @Rahul $\lim\limits_{t\to\infty} t^{-1} = 0$

Comment: Clearly there are two issues. First is that you can't replace the expression with $e^{-n/t} $ and second even if the first issue is ignored you don't get $1/e$ but $1$.

Comment: And why take so much detour when the job is done simply.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in comments, directly take the limit first on $t$ to get $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} 1 =1$.

Secondly, $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to \infty}e^{-n/t}=e^0=1$.

Answer (score 0):

You write

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-n/t}=\frac1e$$

but this is not justified because it is said nowhere that the ratio $\dfrac nt$ tends to $1$.

The correct way is

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\lim_{t\to\infty} e^{-n/t}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}1=1.$$